# Is there any way to build iOS 15 apps with Xcode 12.x?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12, ios15

I'm using MacBook Pro mid 12.
When I try to install Xcode 13 I can't do it. Apple says you need to use macOS 11 but my computer doesn't support it.

Now I need to update my app to iOS 15.
Is there any way to create iOS 15 apps with Xcode 12?

Comment: You can't build an app that targets iOS 15 only and uses iOS 15 features without the ios15 SDK in Xcode 13. An app built against the iOS 14 SDK will, of course, run on an iOS 15 device. At some point, probably around March 2022, Apple will require all new app submissions to use the iOS 15 SDK.

Comment: Thank you, Paulw11. I found a patch to help upgrade my Mid2012 MacBook pro to MacOS Big Sur, even my MacBook is on the incompatibilities list. If you find solutions and questions are useful please vote for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way.
A man whose name is Ben S*** shares a patch on GitHub.
This patch has helped upgrade my MacBook pro mid 2012 to Big Sur OS from MacOS Catalina.

https://github.com/Ben216k/Patched-Sur

After the upgrade, I could install XCode 13 and build my app based on iOS 15.

Comment: This url is not working

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm not sure why he removed it from Github. I saw this documentation when I was looking for a solution. I hope it helps you. https://bensova.gitbook.io/big-sur/

Comment: try [this link](https://github.com/Ben216k/Patched-Sur). it’s the same guy (Ben). i am trying to install it on mid 2012 right now!

Comment: Hi @TheAlienMann, yes it seems same, thanks.